# Requests module 405 Client Error where as urllib3 works fine

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, urllib3

Not able to get data using requests module.

```
import requests
resp = requests.get("https://www.embassy-worldwide.com")
resp.status_code
```

Below code is working fine.

```
import urllib3
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request('GET', 'https://www.embassy-worldwide.com/')
r.status
```

Are there any parameters to set in the requests.get command to make it work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are scraping or sending request, then the website needs to know that it's coming from a browser, hence add relevant headers.

```
In [57]: headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}

In [58]: import requests
    ...: resp = requests.get("https://www.embassy-worldwide.com", headers=headers)
    ...: resp.status_code
Out[58]: 200
```